# x icon disappears in Webflow

Tags: css, animation, content-management-system, webflow

We have noticed X icon disappears in Safari on Mac on Large and Small devices when menu is opened.
Our website:
https://www.symplicit.com.au/

Tried to look at the original template and noticed the problem is the same.
Original template:
https://revolver-cms.webflow.io/

Do you know what the problem might be inspecting the elements in Dev Tools?

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)